# opencv is refusing to import because libcblas.so.3 is missing

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to build a text recognition system from images and I decided to use opencv and pytesseract to do this.

I'm new to using a raspberry pi so I'm using the thonny python ide that came preinstalled on the legacy os. I'm running the legacy os because I'm using a camera module to capture and save the images.

I pip installed both and both commands in the terminal stated that they were both successfully installed. Pytesseract appears to be working fine when I import it but opencv always throws an import error stating

> libcblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You may need to install `libatlas3-base` (Debian-based systems) or whatever the equivalent on other distros.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new to a raspberry pi. I've tried following some tutorials and all of them say to run update and upgrade but every time I do some of the lines show errors. Words like "failed to fetch", "NOSPLIT", and stuff about not being done securely. I'm working at school so I don't no if the internet connection is the problem or if something is wrong with the pi.

Comment: That sounds like you aren't connected to the internet, yes. Those errors are important and should not be glossed over.